# Do PostgreSQL toasted fields use any per row, in-table space?

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I understand that PostgreSQL will store large fields in a separate storage space automatically. When this occurs, is there anything stored per row for that field in the table? A reference or hint of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see [`TOAST` in Database Physical Storage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html)

> TOAST usurps two bits of the varlena length word (the high-order bits
>   on big-endian machines, the low-order bits on little-endian machines),
>   thereby limiting the logical size of any value of a TOAST-able data
>   type to 1 GB (230 - 1 bytes). When both bits are zero, the value is an
>   ordinary un-TOASTed value of the data type, and the remaining bits of
>   the length word give the total datum size (including length word) in
>   bytes. When the highest-order or lowest-order bit is set, the value
>   has only a single-byte header instead of the normal four-byte header,
>   and the remaining bits give the total datum size (including length
>   byte) in bytes. As a special case, if the remaining bits are all zero
>   (which would be impossible for a self-inclusive length), **the value
>   is a pointer to out-of-line data stored in a separate TOAST table**.
>   (The size of a TOAST pointer is given in the second byte of the
>   datum.)